# How can i access another DOM (Yahoo Finance) Dynamically, from my JS file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I'd like to get some data regarding stocks from :http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL
and i'm wondering if there is any way to accees the DOM of this page from my application.
Let's say i have the this query: http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL, i tried to access the DOM from the Chrome console : console.log (document.head.innerText), but o couldn't find a way to access it using my local script file.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to access directly the content of that page from another page in Javascript, because of [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) (given that your app is a website on another domain).
The best way would be to write a backend working as a proxy and API for your app.
Or maybe Yahoo finances already has a public API ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can't access the DOM with cross domain. In other hand you can make a GET request with jQuery before exploit the DOM.

Comment: And then you hit the same origin policy and access is denied.

Comment: If your provide an example it would be a much more useful answer.